# Panda array splicing

Tags: python, pandas, select

I am working on a NBA dataset and I need to do the following: On the given panda array I need to extract rows where the PER is maximized for every different season:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGAfe.png)

Applied to this image, I should get only 2 rows: the row 4607 and 3800
I have struggled in python to splice them for a while even if it seems easy.
Thank you for any tips!

[Edit]
a minimal reproducible example would be the following:
on the array

```
[['id', 'PER','Team'],
['1', '12','OKC'],
['2', '14','OKC'],
['3', '11','GSW']]
```

we should obtain

```
[['id', 'PER','Team'],
['1', '14','OKC'],
['2', '11','GSW']]
```

Comment: please add a [mcve] images are generally not accepted as they aren't reproducible and in your case don't add any value.

Comment: `df.groupby("Team").max()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby("Team").apply(max).reset_index(drop=True)
```